# Missing artifact gnujaxp:gnujaxp:jar:1.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cewolf

I am using cewolf (de.laures.cewolf) in one of the project and I have used the following for Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>cewolf</groupId>
<artifactId>cewolf</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For this I am getting dependency artifact missing error

> Missing artifact gnujaxp:gnujaxp:jar:1.0.0

Thus I have added

```
<dependency>
<groupId>gnujaxp</groupId>
<artifactId>gnujaxp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

However despite adding the above, I am not able to get rid of 
`Missing artifact gnujaxp:gnujaxp:jar:1.0.0`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try to add the gnujaxp repository ?
http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/gnujaxp/gnujaxp/1.0.0/

Comment: In your pom.xml in the balise <repositories>, try to add
<repository>
            <id>repo.pentaho.org</id>
            <name>repo.pentaho.org-snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>
I think it could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pom.xml you should add repository with that artifact.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo.pentaho.org</id>
            <name>repo.pentaho.org-snapshots</name>
            <url>repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```

After that you will be able to download this artifact normally.